# Get all the groups the user belongs to

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

There are two domains Domain A and Domain B having mutual trust between them (forest level trust).

'DomainA\BiggerGroup' is a user group (Domain local scope) in domain A.

'DomainB\SmallGroup' is a user group (Global scope) in domain B.

DomainA\BigGroup contains  DomainB\SmallGroup as a sub-group. And DomainB\SmallGroup contains DomainB\User as a member.

Query:

As an Administrator of DomainB, Can we programmatically list all the groups that DomainB\User belongs to?

WindowsIdentity.Groups is not enumerating DomainA\BiggerGroup.  Is there any way we can list all the groups that a user belongs to (including the groups in the trusted domains)?

(WindowsIdentity Class has Group property which "Gets the groups the current Windows user belongs to."  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with two domains having forest level trust between them. I think that you can try again using WindowsIdentity.Groups, but establishing a connection (principal context) with a Global Catalog (GC) Directory in spite of any other DC directory.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, a user may have different group list when log on to different domain.
This is because domain-local group is **local to group's own domain only** (as its name suggest).

In your case:

- When DomainB\User log on to DomainA, the group list contains DomainA\BiggerGroup and DomainB\SmallGroup
- When DomainB\User log on to DomainB, the group list contains DomainB\SmallGroup

In general, the group list of a user will contains:

1. Global & universal groups from USER domain (DomainB in your case), plus
2. Domain-local groups from connected domain
   (or COMPUTER domain if you are logging on a computer)
3. Other well-known groups, like "Authenticated Users", "Everyone"
   (can ignore this if you are only interested in AD groups)

So, w.r.t which domain you want to find out the group list of DomainB\User?

**Solution:**

To get an accurate group list of a user (without providing password of that user), you can make use of the S4U Kerberos Extensions. (See the S4U2Self section in link below)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188757.aspx

The link suggest to use `WindowsIdentity`. But the `WindowsIdentity` solution has one problem.

```
// parameter must be in upn format
WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity("User@DomainB.com");
```

The problem is you cannot control from which domain to get the domain-local groups.
e.g. On computer joined to DomainA, log on as user in DomainB, get WindowsIdentity for user in DomainC. It will get domain-local groups from Domain A, B or C?

Or you may use the `LsaLogonUser` Win32 function as mentioned in the link. But it takes 14 parameters...
I never tried that before, can't comment on this.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately this did not help as it list out the groups only in DomainB :(

Comment: This depends on who is running the code. If current user is from DomainA, it will get DLG from DomainA plus global+universal group from forest of DomainB.

Comment: The current user is from DomainB :(

Comment: Then there is no easy way. :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the token groups for the user. It will return all effective gorup memberships both direct and indirect due to nesting including other domains.

```
    // this method will return all groups where the the user is a direct and indirect member of
    public static bool getTokenGroups(string domainFQDN, string alias, ref List<string> userGroups)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            SearchResult sr = default(SearchResult);
            using (DirectoryEntry domainDE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainFQDN, "domain\\cn", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domainDE))
                {
                    searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", alias);
                    sr = searcher.FindOne();

                    if (sr != null)
                    {

                        using (DirectoryEntry user = sr.GetDirectoryEntry())
                        {
                            user.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });

                            for (int i = 0; i < user.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count; i++)
                            {
                                SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])user.Properties["tokenGroups"][i], 0);
                                NTAccount nt = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                                //do something with the SID or name (nt.Value)
                                if(nt.Value.IndexOf('\\') > -1)
                                    userGroups.Add(nt.Value.Split('\\')[1]);
                                else
                                    userGroups.Add(nt.Value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("source name", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "\r\n\r\nUnable to get user's token groups for domain: " + domainFQDN + " user: " + alias + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately this did not help as it list out the groups only in DomainB :(